# How to create a row of 3 images until nth image and the last image should have a + icon to upload new image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want a + button at the end of all images, in case 1 there should be only this 1 button on-screen if no image is available and else after the available images this button would be on last of all images, but I want to make this button look same as these images and also in row of 3
My code for the flat list is as below.

```
  <FlatList
       numColumns={3}
       data={this.state.images}
       renderItem={({ item }) => <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Image style={{ margin: 5, height: 120, width: 120 }} 
                   source={{ uri:'data:image/png;base64,' + item.image }} />
                   </SafeAreaView>}
       keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the + in a span whose position is absolute and wrap the last image in it. There's more styling to do here, but this is the start.

The function that adds the image should remove the span wrapper from the old last image and add it to the new one

Comment: actually there the images can be of any no, I want to dynamically setup image in a row and just a static + button after all the images.

Comment: You can just put the + button after the element that wraps around your images then

Answer (score 0):

```
<FlatList
  numColumns={3}
  data={this.state.images}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
    {(item.index + 1) % 3 == 0 ?
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { }}><Image style={{ margin: 5, height: 120, width: 120 }}
    source={{ uri: 'data:image/png;base64,' + item.image }} />
    {/* you can put your + icon image here */}
  </TouchableOpacity>
  :
  <Image style={{ margin: 5, height: 120, width: 120 }}
    source={{ uri: 'data:image/png;base64,' + item.image }} />
}
</SafeAreaView>}
keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to conditionally render the `FlatList` and add the button on the same "row" as the images.

> I want to make this button look same as these images

Styling is up to you :)

Here's a little [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-vurfb) how it would work.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView
} from "react-native";

const data = [{ name: "first" }, { name: "second" }, { name: "third" }];

class App extends Component {
  renderFlatList() {
    const Item = ({ title }) => {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.listItem}>
          <Text style={{ padding: 10 }}>{title}</Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          numColumns={3}
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => ( <Item title={item.name} />)}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* You probably are using state or props for the data, so this checking is just for the demo */}
        {typeof data !== "undefined" && data.length > 0 && this.renderFlatList()}
        <View>
          {/* You could use <TouchableHighlight /> or whatever suits your needs*/}
          <Button title={"+"} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  listItem: {
    backgroundColor: "gold",
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: I want a + button at the end of all images, in case 1 there should be only this 1 button on-screen if no image is available and else after the available images this button would be on last of all images, but I want to make this button look same as these images and also in row of 3

Comment: That was not your original question, consider editing it.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect the changes in your question